# Trouble connecting to AMLS web service on AKS using Python requests

Tags: curl, python-requests, postman, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am having trouble contacting an AMLS web service hosted on AKS in a vnet. I am able to successfully provision AKS and deploy the models, but I am not able to access the web service using the Python requests module:

```py
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + <AKS_KEY>}
resp = requests.post(<AKS_URI>, json={"data":{"x": "1"}}, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: <AKS_URL> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f33f6035a10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

However, I am able to successfully connect to the web service using Postman:

```sh
curl --location --request POST <AKS_URI> \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <AKS_KEY>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"data": {"x": "1"}}'
```

If I load the AKS service in my AMLS workspace `aks_service.run()` also gives me the same error message. I don't have these problems when I deploy without vnet integration.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are there params in your URL? if so try putting them into a separate argument `params={...}`

Comment: There are no parameters in the URL.

Comment: is the AML workspace in the same vnet as the AKS Service? also what version of the SDK have you been using? also for the `aks_service.run()` error, can you share more code and the full stack trace?

Comment: The AML workspace is not in the vnet. I found my error though, and will post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding an inbound security rule enabled for the scoring endpoint in the NSG group that controls the virtual network.

This should be done so that the scoring endpoint can be called from outside the virtual network (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-secure-inferencing-vnet)), but apparently Postman can figure out how to access the endpoint without this security rule!

Comment: yeah still weird for sure. perhaps [open an issue on the MachineLearningNotebooks repo](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is very weird. My initial reaction was that there's a tiny string formatting issue happening with b/w your `requests` request and your `curl` request. But I see that you're getting the same error with `aks_service.run()`.
Perhaps reading more about [how to secure the deployed service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-network-security-overview#secure-the-inferencing-environment) would help?